# Is there a method to retrieve date format with moment?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, locale

I am using moment. I format my date with `moment().format('LLL')`. Depending on locale it will display the date in the locale format.
However I would need to know what format is used :

In moment js files (inner code), I can find

```
longDateFormat : {
            LT : 'HH:mm',
            LTS : 'HH:mm:ss',
            L : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            LL : 'D MMMM YYYY',
            LLL : 'D MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
            LLLL : 'dddd D MMMM YYYY HH:mm'
        },
```

But I don't know if there is a method to access.

Is there a method to say 'hey moment what is the format for this locale and LL' and it would return D MMMM YYYY.

```
moment().locale('fr').getFormatFor('LL') // output  D MMMM YYYY
```

Thanks,

Stéphane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is added in version 2.8.0 and higher.

`longDateFormat(dateFormat)`

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/